# use wait to wait after all process finished but strange output

Tags: c, linux, fork

I want to do some thing with four parallel process

I first fork onec, and in child and parent fork again to get 4 process.

What I want is do something after all the 4 process finished, so I use the `waitpid(-1, &status, 0);`

and my ideal output is that

```
in

numbers

out
```

but the actual output may sometimes be

```
in

numbers

out

one number
```

and I cannot figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <error.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t cpid, w;
    int status;

    printf("%s\n", "in");
      cpid = fork();
      if (cpid == 0)
      {
          cpid = fork();
          if (cpid == 0)
          {
            printf("%s\n", "1");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
          }
          else{
            printf("%s\n", "2");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
          }
      }
      else{
          cpid = fork();
          if (cpid == 0)
          {
            printf("%s\n", "3");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
          }
          else{
              printf("%s\n", "4");
              //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
          }      
      }
      waitpid(-1, &status, 0); 
      printf("%s\n", "out");
      //do something
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using *waitpid()* with *pid=-1*. It waits for any child process to finish. That means, as soon as any one of the child process finishes, the parent process's *waitpid()* will exit. It will not wait for any other child process to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to handle your scenario is by having signale handler for "SIGCHLD" in your main process and use wait/waitpid to obtain the child exit case. In such case, all your child death can be monitored/notified, as the SIGCLD will delivered to the main process.